# Eclipse Helios on Vista refuses to start

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to create a completely fresh installation of Eclipse Helios on my PC (Vista 32bit). I'm therefore also creating a fresh workspace. Unfortunately, Eclipse refuses to start with the following error message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2011-03-19 22:08:37.669
!MESSAGE File doesn't exist or is a directory!
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\120\data\SCR (The system cannot find the specified path)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.storage.file.FileStorage.saveFile(FileStorage.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.storage.file.FileStorage.stop(FileStorage.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stopIt(SCRManager.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Activator.stop(Activator.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2011-03-19 22:08:37.689
!MESSAGE File doesn't exist or is a directory!
!STACK 0
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\120\data\SCR (The system cannot find the specified path)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.storage.file.FileStorage.saveFile(FileStorage.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.storage.file.FileStorage.stop(FileStorage.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stopIt(SCRManager.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Activator.stop(Activator.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:509)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:690)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try blowing away your configuration directory (D:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration) and then starting again.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to extract eclipse into a folder that contains spaces in its path, especially when on Windows.

I have extracted eclipse directly under my `D:\eclipse` of Windows Vista and it works like a charm.

Comment: Unfortunately, it still gives me the same error but of course with the new path. I installed it under D:\eclipse. Could it be a Java version issue? Also, where have you put your workspace folder?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your thread on [Eclipse Community Forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=660615&S=eff07adeb371a6d2b06e9f63ba9f5380), and the various installation parameters on "[Setting up Eclipse](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/setup-eclipse.html)", as well as the [Eclipse.ini page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini?), I would recommend:

- unzipping an Eclipse distro in a simple path without space and Administrator ACL issue
- changing the `eclipse.ini`, [see this `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) as an example, referencing directly a `jvm.dll` file, and a fresh workspace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Please see my last post in the forum. I'm really stuck ...

Comment: @eric: yes but that was after "porting the installation": what about a fresh installation with an empty workspace and a custom eclipse.ini?